# Hide by CBool Columns, not working

Tags: excel, vba

Does anybody know, why this code isn't polite and hiding my columns by unknown rule?

```
Sub EmptyCol()
Call UnlockS

Dim Table As Range:     Set Table = Range("O_List")
Dim Col As Range
Dim Emp As Boolean

Dim c As Long
'Table.Columns.hide = False
With Table
    For c = 4 To .Columns.Count
    Set Col = .Columns(c)
        If (Application.CountIf(Col, "")) = (.Rows.Count) Then Emp = True
        .Columns(c).EntireColumn.Hidden = CBool(Emp)

    Next c
End With

Call L_ORDER
End Sub
```

v1

```
    for c = 1 to .columns.count
        .columns(c).entirecolumn.hidden = not cbool(application.counta(.columns(c)))
```

Its edited code from my previous post, but now I know that isn't working. It hides also not blank colums. Thx for your help.

Comment: you aren't resetting Emp to be false after each loop. But, there is no need to use Emp at all. (also `CBool(Emp)` is redundant as Emp is a boolean). Instead try `If (Application.CountIf(Col, ""))...etc Then .Columns(c)...etc.Hidden = True: End If`

Comment: thx, just want to learn new function =) its workink, but I still not understand how `(Application.CountA(.Columns(c)) = 0)` return my `rows.count` value and give me True value. if not then answers below are wrong .-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you set Emp back to false. Once it finds a positive result for the if, it's going to hide every column from that point forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub EmptyCol()
    Call UnlockS

    Dim Table As Range:     Set Table = Range("O_List")
    Dim Col As Range
    Dim Emp As Boolean

    Dim c As Long
    Table.Columns.Hidden = False
    With Table
        For c = 4 To .Columns.Count
            .Columns(c).EntireColumn.Hidden = _
                        (Application.CountA(.Columns(c)) = 0)
         Next c
    End With

    Call L_ORDER
End Sub
```